# Detect iPhone/iPad auto-screenlock settings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is is possible for a non-jailbroken app to detect Auto-Screenlock settings (such as if users disabled/enabled auto-screenlock in their device general settings)?

If so, how to implement it?

EDIT:

For business solution: http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/integration/mdm/

As an alternative, it seems possible to set device configurations server-side using MDM.

Comment: are you trying to prevent the screen from locking because of inactivity?

Comment: No, I'd like my users to set screenlock to "on" before they can access parts of app that contain confidential material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is is possible for a non-jailbroken app to detect Auto-Screenlock settings (such as if users disabled/enabled auto-screenlock in their device general settings)?

No, that's not possible.

I don't know whether a jailbroken phone could do it, but a non-jailbroken phone definitely can't.

As a workaround, you could possibly implement your own timer that removes the confidential information after a certain time?